# malloc and free on a Stack in C

Tags: c, stack, malloc, free

I'm trying to write a code that dynamically writes the Coordinates of a Point on the Stack and prints (and frees) them back:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct point{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}; typedef struct point POINT;

struct stackPoint{
POINT myPoint;
struct stackPoint *next;
}; typedef struct stackPoint STACKPOINT;

static STACKPOINT *stacktop = NULL;

void printStackElement(POINT aPoint){
printf(" x:%f \t y:%f \t z:%f\n", aPoint.x, aPoint.y, aPoint.z );
}

void push(POINT pushPoint){
STACKPOINT *newElem = malloc(sizeof(STACKPOINT));
stacktop = stacktop +1;
newElem->myPoint = pushPoint;
stacktop = newElem;
}


POINT pop(){
    POINT b = stacktop->myPoint;
    free(stacktop);
    stacktop = stacktop -1;
    return b;
}


int isEmpty(){
    if(stacktop == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}




POINT readPoint(){
    POINT a;
    printf("Please enter your x-Coordinate: ");
    scanf(" %f", &a.x);
    printf("Please enter your y-Coordinate: ");
    scanf(" %f", &a.y);
    printf("Please enter your z-Coordinate: ");
    scanf(" %f", &a.z);
    return a;
}



int main(){
    char quit = 0;
    while(quit !=1 ){
        printf("\n\n enter 'p' to enter another Point or 'q' to quit: " );
        scanf(" %s", &quit);
        switch(quit){
            case 'p':
                push(readPoint());
                break;
            
            case 'q':
                quit = 1;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    while(isEmpty() == 0){
        printStackElement(pop());
    }
}
```

It prints the last entry but before printing the second to last entry, just an error message appears, that the "pointer beeing freed was not allocated".

I tried running it without the free() command, but then it just prints the first line and infite lines of just 0's

I also tried using the *stackTop pointer as a non static pointer instead of the *newElem pointer but that also didnt work..

Comment: Undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier for a `char`.

Comment: Bad code: `free(stacktop);  stacktop = stacktop -1;`.  Once free'd, `stacktop -1;` is UB.

Comment: I don't know what you think e.g. `stacktop = stacktop +1;` is supposed to do in your `push` function, but I can tell you it won't be good. (It essentially treat `stacktop` as a pointer to an element in an *array*, and make it point to the next element in the array.)

Comment: `char quit = 0;  scanf(" %s", &quit);` -->  `scanf(" %c", &quit);`.

Comment: What you have is a stack implemented as a *linked list*. I recommend you read up more about linked lists and how they work. Try experimenting with a few linked lists variants. Then come back to your stack.

Comment: Oh yes i see that it is supposed to be a linked list. Thank you very much! Our professor wanted us to use this format but never even mentioned something like a linked list, will try it now!!

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be a linked list. Our professor just gave us this exercise and never even mentioned a linked list in any way or form.. Thank you very much, it works now!

I changed the push function to:

```
STACKPOINT *newElem = malloc(sizeof(STACKPOINT));

newElem->myPoint = pushPoint;

newElem->next = stacktop;

stacktop = newElem;
```

and the pop function to:

```
POINT b = stacktop->myPoint;

free(stacktop);

stacktop = stacktop->next;

return b;
```